# How stop sorting firstime with jQuery DataTable Plugin

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable

I am using [jQuery DataTable Plugin](http://datatables.net/) for tables. I get sorted records from database and create HTML tables but jQuery datatable plugin resort it to first column.

**For Example**, I have following table.

```
Person( name, birthdate, memberSince )
```

I get records from database sorted by **memberSince** but jQuery datatable plugin resort it by **name**(first column in html table).

I just want that datatable plugin should not sort it initialy.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to look into the [`aaSorting`](http://datatables.net/usage/options#aaSorting) option.

Your call `dataTable()` call should look something like:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
     "aaSorting": [[ 2, "asc" ]]
} );
```

Comment: I was searching for `"aaSorting": []` and I found it from your link in answer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

No initial order:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
  "order": []
} );
```